# Merging two TRUE/FALSE dataframe columns keeping only TRUE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns in a pandas dataframe, like below:

```
df[1]   df[2]
TRUE    TRUE
FALSE   TRUE
TRUE    FALSE
FALSE   FALSE
TRUE    FALSE
FALSE   FALSE
```

From these two columns, how do I make the following new column:

```
df[3]
TRUE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need the [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) function, like that:

```
df['result_col'] = df.any(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the "or" (`|`) operator.

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [True, False, True, False, True, False], 'b': [True, True, False, False, False, False]})

df['c'] = df.a | df.b
```

With result:

```
       a      b      c
0   True   True   True
1  False   True   True
2   True  False   True
3  False  False  False
4   True  False   True
5  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 2):

For a better performance you could use the underlying numpy arrays and compute the [`np.logical_or`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html) of the two columns:

```
df.loc[:,'logical_or'] = np.logical_or(*df.values.T))

    col1   col2    logical_or
0   True   True        True
1  False   True        True
2   True  False        True
3  False  False       False
4   True  False        True
5  False  False       False
```

---

Some time comparissons:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,(10**6,2)).astype(bool))

%timeit np.logical_or(*df.values.T)
4.98 ms ± 33.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df.any(axis=1)
50 ms ± 292 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df[0] | df[1]
6.57 ms ± 154 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```